# ios - Xcode push file .ipa to itunes connect

Tags: ios, itunes, ipa

I want to push file ipa from xcode to itunes. Unfortunately, the server is always on the alert, I do not know how to fix the stars, look forward to the help. I have entered the correct sign and the Provision
[image]

Comment: Which certificates have you downloaded from Apple ?

Comment: _"... is not signed using Apple submission certificate."_ should give you the hint of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the steps laid out by Apple https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH9-SW1

You need to of created a Distribution Certificate and a distribution provisioning profile. Then compile and sign using those details